# Read information from Android Library Project manifest

Tags: android

I have an Android library project. I include the version of the library in its manifest. I use this version internally, so right now I also have the version stored as a static constant. Is there any way to read the version of the library project from the manifest so I can remove this redundancy? From my searching, I'm guessing that the answer is no, since library project manifests are in essence discarded during the build process.

Comment: The library project manifest is not discarded. It is merged with the application's manifest. The version information on the app is used to find if one version is more recent than the other. So the app's version info is used. The way I see is to write the library version into the BuildConfig via gradle or any other static constant that suits you.

Comment: Thanks @Varun. That might work, but we also need to support other build systems. I guess I will stick with updating it in two places for now.